# Here Maps - Only the last set of data is being fetched:

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

So there are two cases here: Here Maps and TomTom Maps. Using their JS SDK for both cases.

I have been trying to get markers set on a map using lat/long data from my database. I was able to connect to the data base and fetch the data and was also able to display it on the map. 
The code for both of them is pretty much the same. My only problem comes when there is more than one set of data as in, 2 or 3 ids with 2 or 3 different lat/long data.

Problem with Here maps: It's only fetching the last set of data.
Problem with TomTom maps: Its averaging out all the lats and longs and throwing a 3rd location altogether.

Here is my `database.php`

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "admin_abhisar";
$password = "Abhisar@1991";
$dbname = "admin_maps";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT lat, lng from markers ";


$result = $conn->query($sql);


if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $lat = $row ['lat'];
        $lng = $row ['lng'];
        $loc = ($lng . "," . " " . $lat . " " . ";" . " ");
        print_r($loc).""; 
    }
} 
$conn->close();
?>
```

Here is the main `index.php` hiding my api key for obvious reasons:

```
<?php
require 'database.php';
?>
    <html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
    <script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js"
    type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-service.js"
    type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-mapevents.js"
       type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 85%" id="mapContainer"></div>
    <script>
      // Initialize the platform object:
      var platform = new H.service.Platform({
        'apikey': '<key-here>'
      });

      // Obtain the default map types from the platform object
      var maptypes = platform.createDefaultLayers();



      // Instantiate (and display) a map object:
      var map = new H.Map(
        document.getElementById('mapContainer'),
        maptypes.vector.normal.map,
        {
          zoom: 15,
          center: { lat: 19.768893, lng: 73.032100 }
        });


// Enable the event system on the map instance:
var mapEvents = new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map);

// Add event listeners:
map.addEventListener('tap', function(evt) {
    // Log 'tap' and 'mouse' events:
    console.log(evt.type, evt.currentPointer.type);
});

// Instantiate the default behavior, providing the mapEvents object:
var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(mapEvents);


// Define a variable holding SVG mark-up that defines an icon image:
var svgMarkup = '<svg width="24" height="24" ' +
    'xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">' +
    '<rect stroke="white" fill="#1b468d" x="1" y="1" width="22" ' +
    'height="22" /><text x="12" y="18" font-size="12pt" ' +
    'font-family="Arial" font-weight="bold" text-anchor="middle" ' +
    'fill="white">O</texfor( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {t></svg>';


// Create an icon, an object holding the latitude and longitude, and a marker:
var icon = new H.map.Icon(svgMarkup),
    lat = <?php echo json_encode($lat) ?>;
    lng = <?php echo json_encode($lng) ?>;
    coords = {lat: lat, lng: lng},
    marker = new H.map.Marker(coords, {icon: icon});

// Add the marker to the map and center the map at the location of the marker:
map.addObject(marker);
map.setCenter(coords);

// Add the marker to the map:


    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

What am i doing wrong? 
What I am expecting is to get individual markers for individual locations. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$lat` and `$lng` variables store only one value, so in your loop, you overwrite the value each time. And at the end, you have only the values of the last row to process.

You need to store all your values in an array :

```
$coords = array() ; // store all coordinates
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $lat = $row ['lat'];
        $lng = $row ['lng'];
        $coords[] = array($lat, $lng) ; // add a new point to the global array
    }
}
```

and do another loop in the javascript section to display each marker individually :

```
var coordinates = <?php echo json_encode($coords);?> ;
var icon = new H.map.Icon(svgMarkup);

for(let i = 0, len = coordinates.length ; i < len ; ++i)
{
    // retrieve coordinates of point i
    let lat = coordinates[i][0] ;
    let lng = coordinates[i][1] ;
    let coords = {lat: lat, lng: lng} ;

    // build marker
    let marker = new H.map.Marker(coords, {icon: icon});

    // Add the marker to the map and center the map at the location of the marker:
    map.addObject(marker);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man.. it really helped.. Been cracking at this for hours now..

Comment: Hi, Also if i want to add another array in the same manner for name and address. How would i do that?